# Adding field input to a field

Tags: 8, entities

I am creating a custom content type with the following fields:

> - Name
> - Offices(can be many)
> - Address(offices address)

Question is, how can I be able to add address field to each office names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) or [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection).

Basically, the idea with these modules is to group two fields (office + address) as a set within an entity and then embed that entity in your content type.

For Drupal 8, Field Collection recommends using Paragraphs, so that's the module I would use.  For Drupal , I would use Field Collection.